# Java Stack throwing EmptyStackException after push

Tags: java, stack

Below is just one little chunk of my code, I am trying to understand why if I add in the line of code that is commented out it throws an EmptyStackException. I need to add the item at the top of `oneStack` to the top of `twoStack` if there are two null values in a row (generated by calling `items.getNextItem()`). Any insight into why this breaks? Or how I can get the top value of `oneStack` to also be the top value of `twoStack` at that point?

I have tried putting that line of code in an `if`, assigning a variable for the value of `oneStack.peek()`, but none of that has helped either. It is almost as if that one commented out line is emptying the whole stack (??).

Main point: if in that commented out line of code I swap `oneStack.peek()` with any other value, it works just fine. So why does it not work with `oneStack.peek()`?

```
oneStack.push(firstItem);
twoStack.push(firstItem);
nextItem = items.getNextItem();
oneStack.push(nextItem);
twoStack.push(nextItem);
while (!done) {
        if (oneStack.peek() == null) {
            oneStack.pop();
            oneStack.pop();
            twoStack.pop();
            twoStack.push(oneStack.peek()); // the commented out line below causes this line to throw an EmptyStackException if uncommented.
            newItem = items.getNextItem();
            oneStack.push(nextItem);
            if (oneStack.peek() == null) {
                oneStack.pop();
                twoStack.pop();
                //twoStack.push(oneStack.peek()); // if I uncomment this it breaks, but this needs to happen for twoStack to be correct
            } else {
                twoStack.push(nextItem);
            }
        } else if (oneStack.peek() == targetItem) {
            done = true;
        } else {
            nextItem = items.getNextItem();
            oneStack.push(nextItem);
            twoStack.push(nextItem);
        }
```

This is the way that items are being generated:

item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, null, null, item6, item7

In the end, this is what is left of the stacks:
oneStack: item1, item2, item6, item7

twoStack: item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item4, item6, item7
(***item3 is missing***)

twoStack should be: item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item4, item3, item6, item7

Comment: you are popping from oneStack twice then you are peeking. How many items does this stack has?

Comment: @efekctive I need to pop from oneStack twice in order to remove the null value and the Item that is previous to it to start over with the item before that one (sorry for how confusing that sounds). Basically, if a null value is generated, it should be removed from oneStack and so should the previous item, and the item prior to that should be added to twoStack again.

Comment: Ok. but are you sure of the size of the stack at that point? From you code it could be empty or not. what is the size prior to the pushes?

Comment: @efekctive there are six items in the stack when it hits the null value that is popped... null and the previous item are popped off, leaving four items, and if it goes through the loop again then two more are popped off, still leaving two items :/

Comment: The exception is quite clear. What is the size of the stack prior to the loop and after how many iterations the exception happens? Maybe add them to the post ( null, not null, null) in the order they would be popped

Comment: @efekctive I will trace through that now and follow up... Why is it fine popping without pushing onto twoStack, though? Why does pushing onto twoStack cause the exception? (Sorry, but I would really like to understand that.)

Comment: if oneStack is empty peek() will complain

Comment: @efekctive added info on the stacks to the main post. in either case, I am surprised that oneStack is generating correctly without that one line of code, but with it it is not (shouldn't that line not even effect the contents of oneStack??)

Comment: I will start putting this together as an answer

Comment: I will finish in a bit busy now

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/EICo5  There is absolutely no way the exception is being thrown when the stack is full. If you never break out of the loop because `done` is false, eventually `oneStack` becomes empty and an exception is thrown when you call peek. Use a debugger and step through your code.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend before attempting to pop anything off the stack or peek, you first check that it is not empty.  At least it would prevent the exception.

Comment: But preventing the exception without knowing why it happened is as bad. It just delays another crash

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15124865)

Comment: @Joseph:  This seems like a rational reason for me.  `peek()` will throw the `EmptyStackException` if nothing's in it.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your stack is empty after popping off the last thing, then peeking throws an exception because there is nothing in the stack left to peek.

Comment: I understand that, but the stack is quite full when this is happening, so it doesn't make sense to me why it is acting as if it is empty... adding an if around it hasn't helped either :/

Answer (score 0):

Prior to loop:

```
oneStack = item1, item1 (if item1 is in items) or item2
twoStack = item1, item1 (if item1 is in items) or item2 let's assume item2
```

Size is two entering loop.

First, second, third, fourth times around:

```
oneStack = item1, item2 item3 item4 item5 null
twoStack = item1, item2 item3 item4 item5 null
```

Fifth time

```
oneStack = item1, item2 item3 item4 
twoStack = item1, item2 item3 item4 item5 item4
```

Sixth time

```
oneStack = item1, item2 item3 item4 null
twoStack = item1, item2 item3 item4 item5 item4 null
```

Seventh time around:

```
oneStack = item1, item2 item3 
twoStack = item1, item2 item3 item4 item5 item4 item3
```

eighth and nineth times around

```
oneStack = item1, item2 item3 item6 item7
twoStack = item1, item2 item3 item4 item5 item4 item3 item6 item7
```

As you can see it is unclear what the contents of items are at the beginning. I would print to console each pop and the whole stacks after each round. Also print the contents of the stacks and items before entering the loop.